# Как считывать данные с игровых контроллеров?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, api

Я новичок в разработке на Android. Появилась необходимость обеспечить поддержку игровых контроллеров для Android c версией 4.3 и выше. Я нашел информацию на developer.android.com, но с ней сложно разбираться, в скачанном примере очень много не нужного например интерфейсы для обратной совместимости с Android 3.1 и прочее. Есть ли простые beginners guide на эту тему? Не могли бы вы поделиться ссылками и прочим. Любая полезная информация по этой теме.

P.S. Сейчас я пытаюсь подключить геймпад от PS4, но как я понял они работают по стандартам, и обеспечив поддержку одного, в принципе должны работать и остальные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо переопределить 2 метода:

```
 public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event){}
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){}
```

С помощью первого можно получать значения со "стиков", а с помощью второго получать id нажатой кнопки.

Пример использования onKeyDown:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD)
                == InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD) {
            switch(keyCode){
                case 109:
                    // реакция на кнопку с кодом 109
                    break;
                case 108:
                   //реакция на кнопку с кодом 108
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

C использованием onGenericMotionEvent все немного сложнее, описывать все подробно не буду, прочитать об этом можно [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input.html?hl=vi). Пример кода с Android Developer, на выходе дает от [-1:1] по осям x и y. Итоговые значения получаем в методе `processJoystickInput`

```
 public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Check that the event came from a game controller
        if ((event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK) ==
                InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK &&
                event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            // Process all historical movement samples in the batch
            final int historySize = event.getHistorySize();

            // Process the movements starting from the
            // earliest historical position in the batch
            for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                // Process the event at historical position i
                processJoystickInput(event, i);
            }

            // Process the current movement sample in the batch (position -1)
            processJoystickInput(event, -1);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onGenericMotionEvent(event);
    }


    private static float getCenteredAxis(MotionEvent event,
                                         InputDevice device, int axis, int historyPos) {
        final InputDevice.MotionRange range =
                device.getMotionRange(axis, event.getSource());

        // A joystick at rest does not always report an absolute position of
        // (0,0). Use the getFlat() method to determine the range of values
        // bounding the joystick axis center.
        if (range != null) {
            final float flat = range.getFlat();
            final float value =
                    historyPos < 0 ? event.getAxisValue(axis):
                            event.getHistoricalAxisValue(axis, historyPos);

            // Ignore axis values that are within the 'flat' region of the
            // joystick axis center.
            if (Math.abs(value) > flat) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }


    private void processJoystickInput(MotionEvent event,
                                      int historyPos) {

        InputDevice mInputDevice = event.getDevice();

        // Calculate the horizontal distance to move by
        // using the input value from one of these physical controls:
        // the left control stick, hat axis, or the right control stick.
        float x = getCenteredAxis(event, mInputDevice,
                MotionEvent.AXIS_X, historyPos);
       if (x == 0) {
            x = getCenteredAxis(event, mInputDevice,
                    MotionEvent.AXIS_HAT_X, historyPos);
        }
        if (x == 0) {
            x = getCenteredAxis(event, mInputDevice,
                    MotionEvent.AXIS_Z, historyPos);
        }

        // Calculate the vertical distance to move by
        // using the input value from one of these physical controls:
        // the left control stick, hat switch, or the right control stick.
        float y = getCenteredAxis(event, mInputDevice,
                MotionEvent.AXIS_Y, historyPos);
        if (y == 0) {
            y = getCenteredAxis(event, mInputDevice,
                    MotionEvent.AXIS_HAT_Y, historyPos);
        }
        if (y == 0) {
            y = getCenteredAxis(event, mInputDevice,
                    MotionEvent.AXIS_RZ, historyPos);
        }

       // x и y значение осей х и y соответсвенно. 

    }
```